# R package installation error: "cannot remove earlier installation"

Tags: r, package

I'm currently making a R package (**tessellation**) which includes some C code. When I do some modifications and click *"Install and restart"* in RStudio, I get this error:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source tessellation

* installing to library 'C:/PortableApps/R/R-4.1.2/App/R-Portable/library'
* installing *source* package 'tessellation' ...
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
```

When I do "Restart R session" before "Install and restart", sometimes this works, sometimes not. So I have to close the project and reopen it, and this is annoying. Do you know what could I do to work more conveniently?

Comment: Or perhaps `dyn.unload(<shared object>)`? Restarting your R session should have covered both of those bases, though... I don't see how the package can be "in use" after a restart, since RStudio doesn't automatically reload packages (except its own). Was the package loaded in another R session running concurrently?

Comment: It may also help you to read the details in `?install.packages`, which mention some issues unique to Windows.

Comment: @MikaelJagan This seems to work: `dyn.unload(system.file("libs", "x64", "tessellation.dll", package = "tessellation"))`.

Comment: You may still need to call `dyn.unload` in all R sessions with your package loaded. Restarting those R sessions could be done with fewer keystrokes, but destroys your global environment. The correct approach will depend on how you define "convenient".

Comment: @MikaelJagan I'm using only one R session (or more, but not for the package I'm working in). I did a **.Rprofile** file to run the `dyn.unload` by calling a function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be sure that the process is not being used (or loaded into R's search path) for the package. I suggest stopping all R sessions, deleting the installed package folder manually, start an R vanilla session, check the attached packages/search path, and finally attempt re-installation/building the package:

```
# from terminal
R --vanilla

# check search path
ls()
search()

# attempt installing package
devtools::install() # or devtools::build()
```